# Why does Image Magick fail to read fonts?

Tags: command-line, image-processing

I'm trying to create a simple contact sheet of all the photos in a directory using `Montage`:

```
$ montage -font Helvetica -pointsize 10 *.png contact_sheet.jpg
```

However, I keep getting a error reading the font file:

```
montage: unable to read font `Helvetica' @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1239.
```

I've tried several fonts, including Arial, and putting the font name in quotes, but get the same error.

Leaving the `-font` option blank returns:

```
unable to read font '(null)' @ error/annotate.c/RenderFreetype/1239
```

Comment: Try `identify -list font` to see which fonts are available.

Comment: @MarkSetchell It doesn't return anything.

Comment: Have a look here.... http://stackoverflow.com/a/24701602/2836621

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've found that installing GhostScript fixes the problem. Using brew: `brew install gs`